# Subset set a dataframe column based on first row value in R

Tags: r

I have a 1 row dataframe called ff.

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
2   5   9   1   7   6
```

How do I create a single column dataframe (ColContribs) when the a column equals 7

```
E
7
```

Like that..?
I was using

```
ColContribs <- ff[,ff[1,]==7]
```

but i'm getting this error

```
Error in Ops.data.frame(ff[1, ], ColContribs) : 
‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

Paul

Comment: The error is not reproducible, works with me. If you want a data.frame as output, use argument `drop = FALSE`, like this: `ColContribs <- ff[, ff[1, ] == 7, drop = FALSE]`.

Comment: This worked....! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a similar case and it worked as below.

```
library(tidyverse)

a <- 2
e <- 7

lol <- cbind(a,e) %>% data.frame() 

ColContribs <- lol[,lol[1,]==7] %>% data.frame()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ff <- data.frame(A = 2, B = 5, C = 9, D = 1, E = 7, F = 6)

ColContribs <- ff[,ff[1,] == 7, drop = FALSE]
```

Because it's a single element data frame, you need to specify drop == FALSE